# Show and hide the submenu of a menu with more than one option using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, menu, submenu

I have a menu and i am trying to show and  hide the submenu of each option. The HTML struct is the following:

```
<a href="/page" class="menu-option" rev="1">Option 1</a>

<ul id="submenu-1" class="submenu" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="/page">Option A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page">Option C</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="/page" class="menu-option" rev="2">Option 2</a>

<ul id="submenu-2" class="submenu" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="/page">Option C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page">Option D</a></li>
</ul>
```

In JQuery i have this code:

```
$(".menu-option").mouseover( function() {

    var id_option = $(this).attr("rev");

    $("#submenu-" + id_option).fadeIn("fast");

}).mouseout( function() { 

});
```

I don't know what to do in the "mouseout()" event because of this:

1) If the user put the mouse in the option menu and after this put the mouse over the submenu of this option, the submenu must keep open and when the user put the mouse out of the submenu, it must be closed if the user doesn't put the mouse back at the option menu that opened it.

2) If the user put the mouse in the option menu and after this put the mouse over other option menu, the submenu of this option must be closed.

Anybody can please help me to implement this "mouseout()" event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJPXq/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.menu-container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
}
```

​

**HTML**

```
<ul id="submenu-1" class="menu-container">
    <li>
        <a href="/page" class="menu-option" rev="1">Option 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/page">Option A</a></li>
            <li><a href="/page">Option C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="submenu-2" class="menu-container">
    <li>
        <a href="/page" class="menu-option" rev="2">Option 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/page">Option C</a></li>
            <li><a href="/page">Option D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**JS**

```
//Menu system
$('.menu-container li').hover(function() {
    //show its submenu
    $('ul', this).fadeIn(100);

}, function() {
    //hide its submenu
    $('ul', this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

Comment: There is just a problem. Is there a way to define different sizes to option menu and submenu?

Comment: @masimao Using position: absolute will work, but you may need to tweak the CSS depending on your final implementation. Here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJPXq/2/

Comment: It's true, tweaking the CSS it works. Please tell me your opinion, in majority of browsers the menu-container will detect the submenu size even with position absolute?

Comment: @masimao Position absolute takes the element out of the flow of the document so that their size will not affect the containing element. It should work cross-browser. The other option is to have sub-menus appended to the body and positioned under the calling menu, but that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: As the element with position absolute takes out of the flow i am thinking if the "menu-container" which have 150px will always detect the 350px of the "submenu" or if the mouse exceed the limit of 150px the "submenu" will be hidden because the event "hover" is associed at "menu-container li" that is inside of "menu-container".

Comment: @masimao Most modern browser will detect the 350 when the sub-menu is open and will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks for you attention and patience! I will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu-option").mouseover( function() {    
     $(this).next("ul").fadeIn("fast");
  }).mouseout( function() { $(this).next('ul').fadeout(); });
```

Comment: I need to implement the mouseout() event, not the mouseover() =)

Comment: But if the user put the mouse over the submenu, it shouldn't be closed. Any idea?

Comment: `<div class='menu-option' style='overflow:hidden'>
<a href="/page">Option 2</a>
<ul id="submenu-2" class="submenu" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="/page">Option C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page">Option D</a></li>
</ul>
</div>`
and now
 `$(this).find('ul').fadeIn();` and  `$(this).find('ul').fadeout();`